# Datatable filtering: linq vs filter?

Tags: .net, linq, datatable

filtering an memory object ( datatble) :

Is there huge different between doing :

```
    var t = dt.Select("id=2");
```

vs

```
    var g = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(f => f["id"].ToString() == "2");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that `DataTable.Select` needs even more memory than `Enumerable.Where` since the latter is just a loop on the `DataRowCollection` of the `DataTable` whereas the old `DataTable.Select` creates new objects like `Select` or `DataExpression` and it even returns  new objects(`DataRow[]`) from the query. `Enumerable.Where` just uses a predicate in  a loop to determine what to return. It's also executed lazily, so you could just take, say 10 rows from the result.

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(row => row.Field<int>("id") == 2)
             .Take(10); // not possible with DataTable.Select
```

Both are in-memory queries, so there's not a great difference.

I would chose what is more readable, powerful and maintanable and also strongly typed([`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extensions): `Linq-To-DataTable`.

Comment: AsEnumerable by itslef also returns `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>(source);` and a `select` returns also a new `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator` so **both** ( datatable.select and Linq) returns new objects....it sounds like your answer states that only `DataTable.Select` returns new objects.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to go through ASP.net forum thread - [DataTable.Select Vs DataTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault](http://forums.asp.net/t/1614046.aspx/1)

From: [Which one to use; Datatable.Select() or LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385563/which-one-to-use-datatable-select-or-linq)

> LINQ is generally easier to read, on my opinion, than pretty much any
> other form of data filtering and has the advantage over using
> DataTable.Select of being, at least partially, strongly-typed making
> it harder to make mistakes.

LINQ is faster than SELECT for large number of rows, when rows keep increasing, you should see considerable difference.