# Whether to use select or AsEnumerable().Where()

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am using the [`DataTable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) in C#.

I would like to know whether I should use [`DataTable.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) or `DataTable.AsEnumerable().Where()` to search an element in the data table.

```
var filter1 = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(
                  r => r.Field<String>("OBJECT_ID").Contains(val));

var filter2 = dataTable.Select(filter expression);
```

Comment: try this link
[Datatable filtering: linq vs filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192215/datatable-filtering-linq-vs-filter)

Comment: How does this get three upvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ is faster than SELECT for large number of rows, when rows keep increasing, you should see considerable difference.
Also linq will generate less memory space compare to select().
I prefer to go with linq because the code will be more readable.

See for clear information [Click Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1614046.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not only about performance, DataTable.Select is hard to maintenance and difficult to write code.

I think the reason it still exists is to allow legacy software to run on.